# phpMailer: SMTP could not authenticate

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHP Mailer on my site stopped working suddenly. It was working correctly for months, nothing has been changed, and now it's throwing the error message `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.` and not just to one mail server but to all mail servers I try to use. When I try connecting to these mail accounts using a desktop mail client, it's working fine, so it's something with the site/hosting.

What could be the problem? I contacted hosting support, but they said I probably have the wrong username/password for the mail account, and when I said I could connect via the desktop mail client they said I must have made an error in my scripts, and when I say nothing has been changed for months they just say they don't know how to help me. What could be the problem and how do I test this? I'm sure it's the hosting server's fault, but I can't prove it since I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Then you should check your authentification data. We can't tell you why you can't connect. Try to connect with your E-Mail client to the SMTP server.

Comment: Did you read my question? I tried connecting using a desktop mail client and it works fine, I tried several mail servers, works fine from desktop clients, doesn't work from the site. It worked from the site for 6 months (at least 5 mails sent daily), it doesn't work today. FTP dates indicate no script has been changed for 6 months. You sound just like my hosting provider. The question was - what could it be and how do I test for it?

Comment: just because your desktop client at home works, doesn't mean the same thing will work from a server in a totally different location.

Comment: So that would point to what kind of problem? Could they be blocking the web server from using certain ports? Can I somehow check if they do?

Comment: do you have ssh access to your hosting account? if so use telnet and see if you can connect to the smtp server via port 25.

Comment: Unfortunately no SSH access. Is there some way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all the files into some free hosting websites like http://www.freehosting.com and try running the page. if it works fine there then there is a problem with your hosting server. These type of problem occurs most of the times due to problem with the hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the line

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

it was working fine for months, but today they changed something, and commenting this line out solved the problem.